# Difference between the three Firestore Python packages

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

Simple question, in Python you can import the Firestore library from three different sources. I can't seem to find any documentation on what the differences are.

All three are official libraries from Google:

> from firebase_admin import firestore

> from google.cloud import firestore

> from google.cloud import firestore_v1

Anyone that can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

Let’s see what all 3 does and how it does:

1. [**`firebase-admin`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.firestore) library allows you to interact with Firebase services, including Firestore, from your server-side code. It needs to be installed separately in the project and requires authentication to be able to use it. So this is the best approach when you are using other firebase services as this one package has all authentication, firestore, realtime database, storage , functions etc.
2. [**`google.cloud.firestore`**](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/index.html) library allows you to interact with the GCP services from your local machine (assume like gcloud installed on your machine). It does not require any authentication to use.
3. [**`google.cloud.firestore_v1`**](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/google.cloud.firestore_v1.aggregation) link is for first item in firestoreV1 : This library provides low-level API for interacting with FIrestore. This library allows you to directly call Firestore REST APIs and provides more control over the requests and responses.

So TLDR use `firebase-admin` when building stuff with Firebase Services, works great if you use firebase functions. If you are creating python applications which use GCP services then use `google.cloud.firestore` or `google.cloud.firestore_v1` if you need more granular control over the API.